# Cassandra update process clarify

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

When we execute a read query it will retrieve data from SStable if it is true. 
then, What will happen if I retrieve the last updated data before compaction happens?
in other words what Cassandra does to retrieve data which in memtable but not in SStable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a diagram of the Cassandra read path.

[image: Cassandra read path]

There are processes which check both RAM and on-disk for the requested data.  When data is found from multiple paths, it is reconciled (to ensure most-recent timestamp) and returned.

So to answer your question, when requested data is not present in a SSTable, the results from a memtable can be returned.

Comment: Why Cassandra checks the both tables? Once data is found in memtable which is the most recent timestamp. So why it check sstable too? If data is not found in memtable it will check the sstable is reasonable think.

Comment: timestamp could be explicitly set on the query, or old data could come late, so data in memtable could be "older" than data on disk.